# why prefix type of url-pattern did not work?(tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

I have a request URL of `hhhhttttppp://localhost:8180/myweb/ws/comment/save` and
below is my `web.xml`. I want to understand why it didn't dispatch my request to my process class.

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` Works well.
`<url-pattern>*.aa</url-pattern>` Works well (change some code for save.aa)
`<url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>` Didn't work.

Can anybody can give some tips?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name></display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myweb.comment</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: can you also provide the context definition for this application from your server.xml?

Comment: have you tried this? : `<url-pattern>ws/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: context is <Context docBase="/home/lifeix/workspace/lifeix-comment/WebRoot"

         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="false">    @Heidarzadeh   ws/* is a invalide url-pattern

Comment: "hhhhttttppp://"? I'd be surprised if the request even got to the Tomcat server!

Comment: in fact it's http://..  --|||

Comment: I find the answer is jersey will remove the prefix of the pattern after deliver

Answer (score 0):

/ws will only match that exact path (relative to the context)

To catch all below, use /ws/

Note, the last does NOT match /ws

To get both, you need two mappings